# Rails API new user not created in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-api

I am working with an API endpoint for registering new users. I can add users locally with cURL:
 `curl -X POST -d email="usrname@example.com" -d password="APassword!" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/registrations/`, will successfully add a user.

But if I write a test for the endpoint:

```
  test 'Should register a new user' do

      user_params = { user: {
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    password: Faker::Internet.password
  } }

    post '/api/v1/registrations', params: user_params
                                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    user = User.find_by(email: user_params[:user][:email])
    assert_not_nil user
  end
```

This will fail and user will be nil: `Expected nil to be truthy.`

One thing I read is that with Rails you don't have to specify the header type `application/json` in a request if it's defined correctly in the routes or controller.  This seems to be the case because I am not passing headers into the cURL request.  I've tried removing the `headers:` from the test:

```
  post '/api/v1/registrations', params: user_params.to_json
```

but I have the same issue, the test result remains the same.

The actual registrations_controller.rb looks like this:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(sign_up_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user
    else
      render json: { errors: @user.errors }
    end
  end

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

Comment: Can you try  `post '/api/v1/registrations', params: user_params`

Comment: I'm getting the same issue and failed test.

Comment: usually, we test by `expect(response).to be_successful` to test if user successfully created. and further you want to test with emails you should check response which you received, are you returning emails back when record created? then you can check     `expect(json).to be_kind_of Hash` 
expect(json['email']).to eq(params[:user][:email]) As for your scenary you should to puts `user` object to see what you get when you run this query.

Comment: You don't need to manually encode the parameters as JSON - just pass a hash -`params: user_params` this could be causing a double encoding issue. In general in Rails if you are ever calling `.to_json` on an object you're probably doing it wrong. Also since you are declaring `user_params` as a local variable in that scope it will not generate unique values per example. You want to use a before/setup block/method or a method that memoizes the value like RSpecs `let`.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar the user object is returned by the `create` method in the registrations controller:    `render json: @user`.  

I did a `response.body`  to see what was coming back and I'm getting: 
`{"errors":{"email":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank","Passwords must be at least 8 caracters long"]}}, response` 

I double checked the `user_params` and this is what was passed in: `{:user=>{:email=>"delbert@christiansen.com", :password=>"1ItNuTgMhSqCs0"}}`

Comment: @max I've added my `registrations_controller.rb` because I think that is the central issue rather than the test, that said I have removed the JSON serializer and added the user_params into the test block (updated to reflect this).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the user_params.  The `sign_up_params` was expecting an email and a password rather than a user object (which I was using to nest the email and password).  Also, password confirmation was expected.

```
  def sign_up_params
    params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

So changing user_params to:

```
    pass = Faker::Internet.password
    user_params = {
      email: Faker::Internet.email,
      password: pass,
      password_confirmation: pass
    }
```

has worked, I think the great suggestions from everyone else (such as removing the `to_json` method from the params hash) also allowed me to move smoothly past this.

I don't know if I should be wrapping my API call in a `user` object or not I've never built an API before.  I'm just trying to mirror what I've done with other Rails projects but adding JWTs and API specific endpoints.

Comment: Itis your choice, some people like to send json request wrapped in user: {} and some just send {email: '' ...} so it is your choice and your frontend people requirements. but in standards I think they prefer to have user: { ....} style.